# How to prevent text column filter apply when entered doesn't meet requirement?

Tags: ag-grid, ag-grid-react

I have a requirement to allow filter only when filter text is more than three characters. Is there any way to put some validation logic somewhere?

Looked at the ag-grid custom filter document but don't know which way is best to accomplish this with minimal coding. Looked at `onFloatingFilterChanged` in `IFloatingFilterParams`, `onFloatingFilterChanged` in Custom Floating Filter, and `isFilterActive` in `IFilterComp` but documentations are all fuzzy and there's no specific example for this purpose.

Anyone tried to implement this?
What's the best way to accomplish this?

Comment: See [ask], and especially [mcve]. The idea is you describe what you want to do, show what you tried, and tell us what results you get. Reproduce your issue on plunk or stackblitz so that others can help you easily.

Comment: Solved this with custom floating filter with `onFloatingFilterChanged` implementation following the [example](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-floating-filter-component/#custom-floating-filter-example)
```this.onFloatingFilterChanged = change => { const { minChars } = this.state; if(change && change.model && (!change.model.filter || change.model.filter.length >= minChars)) { return props.onFloatingFilterChanged(change); } return false; };```

Answer (score 0):

Solved this with custom floating filter component with `onFloatingFilterChanged` implementation following the [example](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-floating-filter-component/#custom-floating-filter-example)

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);

  this.state = {
    minChars: props.minChars ? props.minChars : DEFAULT_MIN_CHARS,
  };

  this.onFloatingFilterChanged = change => {
    const { minChars } = this.state;
    if(change && change.model && (!change.model.filter || change.model.filter.length >= minChars)) {
      return props.onFloatingFilterChanged(change);
    }
    return false;
  };
}
```